# Is there a quick way to move a keyframe to a specific frame?

Tags: animation, workflow, dopesheet

What is the easiest/fastest way to move a keyframe to a specific frame?

In other words, is there a way to type in an absolute frame value with modal numinput (which uses the delta by default)? E.g. type <kbd>G</kbd>`140` to move a keyframe to frame `140`?

Comment: This is old but I just added a [proposal](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/1ghbbc/) to make double `G` switch to absolute keyframe placement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latest development version (after official 2.69), you can type with math, like this:

**<kbd>G</kbd>`target_frame`<kbd>-</kbd>`current_frame`**

**e.g.:** If you want to move keyframe from 120 to 140, you can type <kbd>G</kbd>`140`<kbd>-</kbd>`120`.

**Tip:** it also supports copy/paste feature, which means, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on the current frame number displayed on Timeline header, then <kbd>G</kbd>`140`<kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>), which makes it relatively quicker.

But indeed, a one-stop method may be useful here.

Comment: Fastest so far, but I wish there was a modifier key or something to move keyframes with absolute frame values..

Comment: For anyone else who finds this, the 'G' command in this context is the action 'Transform: Translate' if you can't remember what the obscure magic shortcut is.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the best you can do is type the preferred frame into the Timeline 'Current frame' field then apply a Snap to (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) frame function on the selected Keyframe.

It would be neat to have another snap to function as you suggest to reduce the amount of mouse clicks involved.

Comment: Agree. It would be neat to implement sort of Offset snap to support multi-frame offset, (Shift S currently only work with single frame) just like the **Snap to Cursor (Offset)** function for snapping in 3D View.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is:

1. Open a new editor window and set it to the *Action Editor*.
2. Go the Top of the *Action Editor* and select the frame you want to move.
3. Press <kbd>G</kbd> and click where you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was hoping for a way to type the frame number with the keyboard. Sometimes with long animations and scenes with many frames it can require a lot of scrolling and zooming to be able to click accurately. I'm trying to find a faster way to do this.

Comment: Oh ok :) ... i just realised its you lol