# How do I jump to a keyframe time on the dope sheet?

Tags: keyframes

In After Effects, I could easily select a keyframe, right click it, and click "Go to keyframe time" so I could easily line up other keyframes to it and do other useful things, but how do i do this in Blender?

Comment: related:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7506/keyframe-help-with-arrow-keys

Comment: also related somehow... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6630/is-there-a-quick-way-to-move-a-keyframe-to-a-specific-frame/6633#6633

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Dope Sheet Editor or the Graph Editor you can select the keyframe and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Or use the menu Key->Jump to keyframes.

[image]